# UIBarButtonItem with custom view doesn't work with UIHostingController

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

Assume we have `UIWindow` with `UINavigationController` as `rootViewController`.

```
window = UIWindow()
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
window.rootViewController = navigationController
```

And then a basic `UIHostingController` with some dummy SwiftUI view.

```
let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: SomeView())
navigatonController.setViewControllers([controller], animated: false)
```

My problem is, that when I want to add `UIBarButtonItem` to `UIHostingController` it doesn't work and act like its `nil` (no frame in Debug View Hierarchy).

```
controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: CustomButton())
```

When I change the exact same code from `UIHostingController` to just `UIViewController` it works fine.

```
controller = UIViewController()
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use working variant with

```
let controller = UIViewController()
controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: CustomButton())
```

and inject hosting controller as child of that controller

```
let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: SomeView())
controller.view.addSubview(hosting.view)

// set up view constraints here for `hosting.view`

controller.addChild(hosting)
hosting.didMove(toParent: controller)
```

Comment: Yeah, could be potential solution, but do you have any idea why we need to introduce parent UIKit view controller instead of setup items on UIHostingController directly?

Comment: I’m just curious is that just an Apple bug, or intended case

Comment: UIKit flows should live in UIKit, SwiftUI flows should be in SwiftUI - just by experience. UIHostingController is just kind of bridge, no more.

Comment: @TanyaMarchuk the above solution is not working, it is not showing the hostingviewcontroller view hence it's showing black screen